# Examples of non-trivial determiner formulas of trnsitive models of ZFC

Tags: logic, set-theory

**Notation:** For each $\{\in\}$-formula $\varphi(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ and each $\in$-model $M$, define: $$\varphi (M)=\{(a_{1},\cdots,a_{n})\in M^{n}~|~\langle M,\in\rangle\models \varphi (a_1,\cdots,a_n)\}$$

**Definition 1:** An $\{\in\}$-formula $\varphi(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ is "determiner" for transitive set models of ZFC if for all transitive set models of ZFC like $\langle M,\in\rangle ,\langle N,\in\rangle$ we have:

$$M=N \Longleftrightarrow \varphi (M)=\varphi (N)$$

**Definition 2:** A set of $\{\in\}$-formulas $\Sigma$ is "determiner" for transitive set models of ZFC if for all transitive set models of ZFC like $\langle M,\in\rangle ,\langle N,\in\rangle$ we have:

$$M=N \Longleftrightarrow \forall \varphi\in \Sigma~~~~~\varphi (M)=\varphi (N)$$

**Remark 1:** A trivial example of a determiner formula is $\varphi (x):x=x$. In fact in order to compare the domain of discourse of two transitive models of ZFC, it suffices to compare the set of solutions of a determiner formula in two models.

**Question:** What are some non-trivial examples of determiner (set of) formulas for transitive models of ZFC?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a class of examples.

Let $\varphi(x)$ be a formula defining an absolute inner model $J$. Namely, $\varphi(M)=\varphi(N)$ if and only if they have the same ordinals (e.g. the definition of $L$). Now take $\lnot\varphi(x)$ as our formula, then we have that $\lnot\varphi(M)=M\setminus J^M$ and $\lnot\varphi(N)=N\setminus J^N$. If the two classes are equal, then necessarily the two models are equal.